# Meteor project giving npm module error whenever switching OS

Tags: node.js, git, meteor, operating-system

I have a Windows Laptop, and a Linux desktop. 
Whenever I switch from my Laptop to my desktop (my Meteor project is on Dropbox, so it syncs), I can't get my Meteor project to run, getting the following error:

> Error: Can't find npm module 'double-ended-queue'. Did you forget to
>   call 'Npm.depends' in package.js within the 'meteor' package?

The odd thing is, I've tried removing `.meteor/local` , and since my project is a git repo, I could easily check and see that `git diff` is not giving anything, so I'm not sure what changed.

Any ideas about how I could solve this issue?

Comment: Oddly enough, I'm getting this error on other projects as well, fixable only via removing and re-installing meteor from the system.

Comment: It's likely that Meteor uses OS-specific libraries. Sharing them through Dropbox will probably not work. To be safe, don't keep the libraries in Dropbox - install/update them locally on each machine.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because meteor builds your project according to your OS it is recommended you ignore .meteor/local directory from syncing. That is why it is added to your .gitignore file by meteor automatically, hence no result on git diff.

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox isn't really a suitable place to store code. Meteor uses a .gitignore file to avoid the problem you're having, which implies that they expect you to be using git repositories. Depending on your needs you could try GitHub (https://github.com) or BitBucket (https://bitbucket.org). BitBucket has the benefit of allowing private repositories free of charge.

If you really want to use Dropbox you should be able to ignore the .meteor/local folder with selective-sync. More info at https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/175

In terms of the reason for the synced code not working when you switch OS, it is because meteor compiles packages into the .meteor/local directory. Some but not all of this code is OS-specific (basically any binary packages will fail if you switch OS because they are compiled for your specific OS and processor architecture).